# Decrease the space between Vcc and Rc

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How can I decrease the space between the Vcc and the Rc resistor?

Currently I have the following piece of code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
                (0, 0) node[anchor=east] {A}
                to[short,o-*] (1,0)
                to[R=$R_1$] (1,4)
                (1,4) -- (3,4)
                (3,4) node[vcc]{$V_{cc}$}
                to[short] (3,3)
                to[R=$R_{c}$] (3,1)
                (3, 0) node[npn](npn1){NPN}
                (npn1.C) -- (3,1)
                (npn1.B) -- (1,0)
                (npn1.E) -- (3,-1)
                to[R=$R_{c}$] (3,-3)
                to[short] (1,-3)
                to[R=$R_{2}$] (1,-1)
                to[short] (1,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, how do you start drawing such circuits. What are the most important points for placing an element? Is there a good guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I reduce distances for resistors to 2cm, use relative coordinates and introduce three auxiliary coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0)   node[left] {A}
                to [short,o-*] (1,0)        coordinate (rb)
                -- + (1,0)   node[right,npn] (npn1) {NPN}
    (npn1.C)    to [R=$R_{c}$] ++ (0, 2)    coordinate (rc)
    (npn1.E)    to [R=$R_{e}$] ++ (0,-2)    coordinate (re)
    (rb)        -- (npn1.B)
    (rb)        -- (rb |- npn1.C) 
                to [R=$R_{1}$] (rb |- rc) -- (rc) node[vcc] {$V_{cc}$}
    (rb)        -- (rb |- npn1.E)
                to [R=$R_{2}$] (rb |- re) -- (re);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
if you like to have resistors label on the same (right) side:

[image]

then you need to changeoptions for resistors `R_1` and `R_e`:

```
to [R,l_=$R_{c}$] ...
to [R,l_=$R_{1}$] ...
```

Comment: Yes like this, do you know a good tutorial on this?

Comment: @Pascal, no, but if you familiar with TikZ, than use of `circuitikz` is not difficult to use it. In my answer I help myself with macros/commands from TikZ, for example: defining coordinates `rb`, `rc` and `re`; then use of relative coordinates for resistor `R_c`, etc.